# Column order in SugarORM

Tags: android, android-database, sugarorm

I have *Model* class as follows :

```
public class Form_Model extends SugarRecord {
            String date, district,municipality,ward;
            int f1q1, f1q2, f1q3, f1q4, f1q5, f1q6;
            String f1q7, f1q8, f1q9;
            .....
            ..... 
}
```

And *constructor* as :

```
 public Form_Model(String date, String district, String municipality, String ward, int f1q1, int f1q2, int f1q3, int f1q4.....)
```

Everything works fine. But upon looking at the generated *.db* file, the columns are in random order (not as specified in constructor).What should be done to get the columns in order as that of the constructor or in the order I want ?

**EDIT** : Just found out that SugarORM orders the columns in alphabetical order. So, anyway to override that?

Comment: The main question would be: why?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the database with sql if you prefer [Do the next](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/migration.html)